# Python function breaks with string index out of range error

Tags: python, string

I am trying to create a list of chapters from a book text file. But I keep getting an "string index out of range" error.  Here is the code:

```
###Create seperate chapters in the dictionary
def createChapters(bookText):
    startIndex = 0
    endIndex = 0
    counter = 1
    chapters = {}
    ### Now break the book into chapters
    while startIndex != -1:
        startIndex = bookText.find("Chapter"[startIndex])
        
        print(startIndex)
        
        endIndex = bookText.find("Chapter"[startIndex])
        print(endIndex)
        if endIndex != -1:
            chapters[counter] = (bookText[startIndex:endIndex])
        else:
            chapters[counter] = (bookText[startIndex:len(bookText) - 1])
            
        counter += 1
        startIndex = startIndex + 7
        # Now we should have a list of chapters....but not yet
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can do this more easily using a regular expression. `Chapter.*?(?:Chapter|$)`

Comment: regex is next on my list of things to learn, for sure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `startIndex` as an index into the literal string `"Chapter"`. You'll get that error whenever `startIndex` is higher than 6.

It looks like you're trying to start your search from the previous index. That's a separate argument to `find()`, not an index into the argument. So it should be:

```
bookText.find("Chapter", startIndex)
```